# Unable to run gcloud docker push from google compute engine instance

Tags: docker, gcloud, google-kubernetes-engine, google-container-registry

When I do `gcloud docker push`  i get the following error.

```
denied: Unable to create the repository, please check that you have access to do so.
```

`gcloud info` shows correct project name as configured in gcloud.

Can somebody please guide me with this issue? Or suggest an alternative.

I have tried directly logging in without gcloud, login succeeds but push fails

```
$docker login -e 2983212121577-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com -u oauth2accesstoken  -p "$(gcloud auth print-access-token)" https://gcr.io
Flag --email has been deprecated, will be removed in 1.14.
Login Succeeded
$ docker push gcr.io/project/imagename
...
denied: Unable to create the repository, please check that you have access to do so.
```

$ gcloud --version
Google Cloud SDK 147.0.0

$ docker --version
Docker version 17.03.0-ce, build 3a232c8

Answer (score 6):

If you do

`gcloud docker -- push gcr.io/X/Y`

you will need to have permission to write to the GCP named 'X'.  Typically you will need to be added to that project as a project EDITOR.

In this case GCR does not complain about the project shown by 'gcloud info'.

Comment: It is added to project as a 'EDITOR'. Still not working

Comment: I see in your pasted command line you are pushing to the repository 
  `gcr.io/project/imagename`.  Is that right or did you change to avoid showing your image name?  If it is correct name, you will need to be added to the project named `project` as an `EDITOR`.  If you want to keep your project name private, please email `gcr-contact@google.com` directly so we can discuss further through email to assist you.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post. But I couldn't find a good answer when I came here.
gcloud docker -- push is deprecated for Docker clients above 18.03.

You need to use the normal Docker push commands. But before you do first execute the following command. This will configure Docker to use gcloud as an credential helper.

```
gcloud auth configure-docker
```

You will also see that some URL will be added to a config

```
 "credHelpers": {
    "gcr.io": "gcloud",
    "us.gcr.io": "gcloud",
    "eu.gcr.io": "gcloud",
    "asia.gcr.io": "gcloud",
    "staging-k8s.gcr.io": "gcloud",
    "marketplace.gcr.io": "gcloud"
  }
```

After that, you can do a normal docker push and your image will be added to your repo

```
docker push gcr.io/<project-id/<image>:<tag>
```